# The default git commit message is missing

Tags: git, cygwin

I have using cygwin on Windows 8.1 to run git and have

```
editor = "'C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -nosession -noPlugin"
```

in my .gitconfig file.  Notepad++ comes up when I do a git commit command with no message but the file is empty.  The default git commit message is missing so when I save the file I have to pick a name and the commit is aborted because git doesn't know where the message is.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem.  Notepad++ comes up with a blank new file but if I open ~/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG and type in my message it works fine.  The default message is already in COMMIT_EDITMSG. I have to do the same thing if I do a revert.  Cygwin puts in a different default message depending on what you are trying to do.  Thanks for the help!